# linearity of stochastic differential equations

Tags: stochastic-calculus

If

$dX(t) = a_1(t)dt + b_1(t)dW(t)$

$dY(t) = a_2(t)dt + b_2(t)dW(t)$

Can we say that

$d(X(t)+Y(t)) = (a_1(t)+a_2(t))dt + (b_1(t)+b_2(t))dW(t)$  ?

Comment: I feel like it should. But I'll need some work on it.